# ImportError: cannot import name 'QgsGeometryAnalyzer' from 'qgis.analysis'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am trying to do a buffer analysis of my shapefile by Python script but I have this problem in every beginning.

The warning message is: 
**ImportError: cannot import name 'QgsGeometryAnalyzer' from 'qgis.analysis'**

I am using QGIS Desktop 3.6.1.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Should I install **QgsGeometryAnalyzer** manually?

[image]

Comment: The QgsGeometryAnalyzer class was removed from Qgis 3: https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_removed_classes  You should be able to import the processing module and use equivalent processing algorithms instead. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console